# You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Tags: apache, permissions, webserver

I know this has been answered thousands of times already but I still face this issue and I cannot sort it out. I am new into servers. Please help.

I changed user and group to www-data. I set permissions like below.

these are directories/files permissions: (can't include file as server is running on VM)
https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2018/09/18/LrCe.png

Is there a problem with pemissions? Thank you very much for right direction.

Comment: You will need to be much more precise with regards to your setup and your problem. As you say, this is a common problem but it has many different causes.

Comment: Can you copy/paste your apache config file ?

Comment: Thanks for reply, here is my apache2.conf: https://pastebin.com/Ykd8zpnn

Comment: please paste your  /etc/apache2/sites-available/yourappname.conf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace /etc/apache2/sites-available/yourappname.conf file directory settings.

```
  <Directory /path/yourapp/public>
     Allow from all
     Options -MultiViews
     Options FollowSymLinks
     Options All
     require all granted        
     AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
```

Comment: Welcome.  Joe Marks